# PowerBi Api: how to copy cell contents to clipboard using a context menu command

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to just copy the cell contents of a report into the clipboard in my Microsoft PowerBI app.

in my configurations i have this:

```
    settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: true,
        navContentPaneEnabled: true,
        extensions: [
            {
                command: {
                    name: "CopyToClipBoard",
                    title: "Copy to Clipboard",
                    extend:
                    {
                        visualContextMenu: {
                            title: "Copy"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

this brings up a right click menu where i see **Copy** as my new option.

So then i create the method for gathering the data:

```
report.on("commandTriggered", function (command) {
    console.log(command);
    var details = command.detail;
    if (details.command === "CopyToClipBoard") {
 //I thought the selection was in the first DataPoint, first Identity. It's not.
        var dpoints = details.dataPoints[0].identity[0].equals;
        CopyData(dpoints);
    }
});



function CopyData(dpoints) {
    //Get the selected text and append the extra info
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var selection = window.getSelection();


    //hide the newly created container
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    //insert the container, fill it with the extended text, and define the new selection
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = dpoints;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    document.execCommand("copy");

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 100);
}
```

the problem is that the command doesn't contain any element of whats in the cell. It contains only data point/Identity which contains the location or identity of the cell.

How can i just get the cell text??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like as of right now gathering the values are still in progress....
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events